# better use of find - rvm.sh

Tags: bash, shell, find

I am trying to find rvm.sh as I am receiving the infamous rvm is not a function error.

The file in most linuxes is supposed to be at

```
/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

However on opensuse it is not there so I am attempting to use find. Here is how I am using it

```
[sayth ~]$  sudo find / -name 'rvm.sh' 2>/dev/null
root's password:
```

Now the issue is that half an hour has now passed and I am still awaiting a return result. Is there anyway to do this better?

Comment: `locate` is much much faster than `find`.  Unless you think that the file you are interested in was created or moved in the last day or, more accurately, since the last update to locate's database, use `locate` instead.

Comment: @john1024. Tried for some reason opensuse doesn't have locate and couldn't install it via zypper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` is looking everywhere, including in special filesystems. To look only for disk files, at least use:

```
find -xdev / -name rvm.sh 2>/dev/null
```

If you have several partitions, list them all; for example, if you have a separate `/home` filesystem:

```
find -xdev / /home -name rvm.sh 2>/dev/null
```

That being said, `find` is more of a tool of last resort; there's probably a better way. Most distributions set up a [locate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)) database: a database of file names, updated nightly by the `updatedb` program. Run `locate rvm.sh` to find files whose name contains `rvm.sh`.

That being said… `rvm.sh` is wherever you put it. Since it isn't packaged for SuSE (as far as I can tell), you must have installed it manually.